# What is the easiest yet precise method one can make a track and a train

Tags: arduino

I would like to put a train on a track and control its movement with high precision left and right using a wireless controller.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's not clear what you're asking. What size train? What kind of track? How is it powered? How are you typically controlling it? What is "high precision"?

Answer (score 1):

Buy a train set, build it, put the train on it.
Now take the Train track controller take the speed/direction knob off.
Buy a remote control car, take the rear wheel off, hook the axel of the car to the train controller and use the RC controller to control your train.

If you want a more detailed answer then you need to put more detail in your question.
What model train is it?
How do you currently control the trains speed and direction?
What distance does the control need to operate at?
What is your definition of high precision, a few mm or nanometres?
What do you mean by best?  Cheapest, easiest, highest precision?
What is the maximum lag between command and response?

Comment: You're suggesting that he spin the potentiometer at different speeds?

Comment: No, he'd have to use precise thumb movements. :)